# transfering session using session_id across domains

Tags: php, cakephp, sessionid

I am attempting to transfer a session to another domain by using session_id function.

User logs in @ domainA.com and gets redirected to domainB.com where I want to transfer the session.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["redirect"]) && $_REQUEST["redirect"] != ''){
            $url = urldecode($_REQUEST["redirect"]);
            if(strpos($url, "xxxxx.") === false){ //Means we are redirecting to a custom domain
                $urlParts = parse_url($url);
                $url = $urlParts["scheme"] . "://" . $urlParts["host"] . "/login/index/sid:" . session_id() . "?redirect=" . $url;                
            }            
            $this->redirect($url);  
        }
```

SiteB.com will receive the session id and set it like so:

```
if(isset($this->params["named"]["sid"]) && $this->params["named"]["sid"]){          
            session_id($this->params["named"]["sid"]);
            $this->redirect($this->params["url"]["redirect"]);
        }
```

I am sure that the session is arriving at siteB.com but $_SESSION remains empty.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: do both domains have access to the same `session_save_path` from php.ini?

Comment: I have identified the problem: setting the session id must be done before session_start() and one must allow the response to flush to effectively set the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call session_id($sess_id) before session_start();